# Finding the second derivative of a polar equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} =\dfrac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}=\dfrac{f(\theta) \cos \theta +f'(\theta) \sin \theta}{-f(\theta) \sin \theta +f'(\theta) \cos \theta} \\ r=f(\theta), ~~y=f(\theta)\sin \theta,~~x=f(\theta)\cos \theta\\r=\theta$$ This is the formula for the first derivative of polar equations. Using the second line making a few substitutions to find the first derivative we find that $$\dfrac{dy}{d\theta} =\dfrac{\theta \cos \theta +\sin \theta}{-\theta\sin \theta +\cos \theta}$$ which according to te model answer is correct. It is from my understand that the second derivative is found as $$\dfrac{d}{d\theta} \cdot \dfrac{dy}{d\theta}=\dfrac{dy}{d\theta\cdot d\theta}=\dfrac{\theta \cos \theta +\sin \theta}{(-\theta\sin \theta +\cos \theta)^2}$$ however i'm now sure how i would arrive at the model answer of $$\dfrac{\theta ^2 +2}{(-\theta\sin \theta +\cos \theta)^3}$$
Can anyone guide me along the way on how to work this out?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my mistake it should be dx on the bottom.

Comment: Could you explain this line? $$\dfrac{d}{d\theta} \cdot \dfrac{dy}{d\theta}=\dfrac{dy}{d\theta\cdot d\theta}=\dfrac{\theta \cos \theta +\sin \theta}{(-\theta\sin \theta +\cos \theta)^2}
$$

Comment: Am I correct that you actually wanted $\frac{d}{d \theta} \frac{d y}{d x} $ ?

Comment: I do believe i have made a mistake on this line, thanks for pointing this out, so it should be. $$\frac{d\frac{dy/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}$$

Comment: This is just $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$. Please figure out what you mean and fix the post

Comment: Will do please give me a lot of time, i'm not very good at this, sorry.

Comment: The original question was, Compute $$y'=\dfrac{dy}{dx}~~and~~y''=\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$$
and it gave me $$r=\theta$$
i do believe i got the first derivative correct simply that i'm struggling with the second.

Comment: Yes, your first derivative is correct. As well as this expression: $$\frac{d\frac{dy/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}
$$ So now you need to apply that. For simplicity, denote your first derivative as $g( \theta)$ and $x= h(\theta)$ then find $g'/h'$

Comment: I see, so i need to differentiate $$\dfrac{\theta \cos \theta +\sin \theta}{-\theta\sin \theta +\cos \theta}$$  and divide it by $$-\theta\sin \theta +\cos \theta$$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: Thank you, i have found the correct answer. Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: You are welcome